# Get GNU bc to print a newline character

Tags: bc

GNU bc is very unconventional. I can't find anything online about how to get it to print a newline character. I'm trying to get it to print the first 16 hexadecimal digits of the sines of the integers from 1 to 30. I'd expect something like this to work:

```
define mod(x, y) {
    oldscale=scale;
    scale=0;
    result=x%y;
    scale=oldscale;
    return result;
}
obase=16;
x=1;
while (x <= 30) {
    X=2^64*mod(s(x),1)-mod((2^64*mod(s(x),1)),1);
    print X"\n";
    x=x+1;
}
```

But it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Just found another possible problem: if you're using a capital `X` character, this happens when I try using it in `bc`:

```
X=3
(standard_in) 16: illegal character: X
(standard_in) 16: syntax error
```

Apparently only lower case characters are variables (from the man page: *Input numbers may contain the characters 0-9 and A-F. (Note: They must be capitals.  Lower case letters are  variable  names*).

So changing to a different lower case character (since there's already another lower case `x`) would be a good idea.

---

I just tried some very basic testing, apparently using `print` in `bc` makes it **not** print a trailing newline. Just putting the variable / number on it's own line **does** print a newline:

```
$ echo "x=5; print x; print 999; x; 15; print 15; 12345"|bc
59995
15
1512345
```

So, replacing your `print x"\n";` line with just `x;` should work?

And, using a `\n` with print should work too, maybe you had a quoting problem... when I tried echoing to `bc` using double-double-quotes (definitely wrong ;-) or double-quoted with single quoted `\n`s it fails:

```
$ echo "x=5; print x; print 999; x; 15; print "15\n\n\n"; 12345"|bc
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
$ echo "x=5; print x; print 999; x; 15; print '15\n\n\n'; 12345"|bc
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: '
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: \
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: \
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: \
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: '
```

But using single quotes for echo, and double-quotes for the `\n`s it does work

```
$ echo 'x=5; print x; print 999; x; 15; print "15\n\n\n"; 12345'|bc
59995
15
15


12345
```

So, also replacing your `print x"\n";` line with `print "x\n";` should work too?

An informative quote from `man bc`:

> print list
>                The print statement (an extension) provides  another  method  of  output.
>                 The  "list"  is  a  list  of strings and expressions separated by commas.
>                 Each string or expression is printed in the order of the list.  No terminating  newline is printed.  Expressions are evaluated and their value is
>                 printed and assigned to the variable last. Strings in the print statement
>                 are  printed  to  the output and may contain special characters.  Special
>                 characters start with the backslash character (\).  The  special  characters recognized by bc are "a" (alert or bell), "b" (backspace), "f" (form
>                 feed), "n" (newline), "r" (carriage  return),  "q"  (double  quote),  "t"
>                 (tab),  and "\" (backslash).  Any other character following the backslash
>                 will be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

To just print a newline, have a statement which is just string literal containing nothing but a newline. Not `\n`, but a real newline:

```
"
"
```

This should show up as a newline on your output.

Answer (score 0):

The line `print "\n"` prints a newline in bc. The `print` command takes a comma-separated list, so to print a newline after the value of a variable, you need add a `"\n"` to your print list. Your line should be

```
print X, "\n";
```

But as [307834 points out](https://superuser.com/a/874797/228569), you shouldn't use a capital `X` as a variable; [capital letters are reserved as constants/digits in bases greater than 10](https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2019/09/04/more-bc-weirdness/).